Cannot force Ubuntu 24.04 to use my dedicated gpu to run X server using Wayland
On Ubuntu 24.04 with a built-in Intel GPU and a discrete Nvidia RTX 4060 GPU. Absolutely nothing I've tried will get X server to use my dedicated GPU. nvidia-smi shows only the shell where I called the command as running on the GPU:
$ nvidia-smi
Tue Jul 16 18:24:41 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.90.07              Driver Version: 550.90.07      CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 ...    Off |   00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   33C    P8              3W /   55W |     133MiB /   8188MiB |     58%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      4408      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          130MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

My X server conf files also seem to do nothing:
[~]$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/nvidia-prime.conf 
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "nvidia-prime"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "PrimaryGPU" "yes"
EndSection
[~]$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf 
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "intel"
    MatchDriver "i915"
    Driver "modesetting"
EndSection

Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    Option "PrimaryGPU" "yes"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/nvidia/xorg"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
EndSection

prime-select nvidia is no help either as after rebooting it's made no difference:
$ sudo prime-select nvidia
Info: selecting the nvidia profile
Deleting /lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-runtimepm.conf
Updating the initramfs. Please wait for the operation to complete:
Done

Selecting performance mode in Nvidia X server settings is no help either:

My laptop is also set to power mode:

Yet Ubuntu thinks I have 2(!) built-in graphics cards:

And nvtop says all X server stuff is running on my Intel GPU:

Device 0 [NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 Laptop GPU] PCIe GEN 2@ 8x RX: 0.000 KiB/s TX: 0.000 KiB/s
Device 1 [Raptor Lake-S UHD Graphics]         Integrated GPU RX: N/A TX: N/A

Right clicking on apps and using the "launch using discrete gprahics card" option doesn't work either, I can still see the process under the built-in gpu in nvtop.
Similarly, glxgears will also run on the built-in gpu only. The only way I've been able to get it to run on the dedicated one is with a bunch of env variables preceding the call:
vblank_mode=0 __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD_PROVIDER=NVIDIA-G0 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia glxgears
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
265 frames in 5.0 seconds = 52.953 FPS
X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).

I can then see it's my nvidia GPU running it in nvtop.
Some OS deets:
$ uname -a
Linux Laptop 6.8.0-38-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jun  7 15:25:01 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

On the proprietary Nvidia 550, but 535 had the exact same issue, so not down to driver I assume.
My laptop is a lenovo legion pro 5, is this something laptop specific? Wayland related?
edit: Yes, seems like it is Wayland related, switched to X11 (after fixing a typo in one of the X11 config files) and now Xorg runs on my dedicated GPU which has also made a frustrating stuttering issue I had with Chrome with hardware acceleration on disappear too.

Neither laptop nor driver nor Wayland specific.  Hybrid laptops (should) use the intel GPU for screen rendering and the dedicated for creating content, but that sink/source seems to get mixed up (sometimes, more lately).  When running xorg, you can see the (mixed up) sink/source via xrandr --listproviders. The CUDA graphics samples wont even run without the env var fix (which does work with Wayland, even if xrandr --listproviders doesn't).

@ubfan1 so one reason I want to use my dedicated GPU to run X is because Chrome hardware acceleration doesn't seem to work with my integrated GPU, I've had to disable it, otherwise I'd get really random stuttering. So the mixing up is inevitable and I basically can't do anything? And anything I want to send to the dedicated GPU I always have to use the env var fix?

You can just set the env variables in your .profile (and export them), then they don't need to be set on the invocation lines. I never bothered as there was no pattern on when the switch occurred on the sink/source, but now it's pretty constantly the wrong way, I may reconsider as some games seem to be overheating without doing something.

I reckon this is Wayland related, I switched to Xorg (cog thing at login) and that seems to run on my dedicated gpu by default, I now see Xorg running on in nvidia-smi
